# Add/Create New User in SendBird

Tags: sendbird

I am trying to use sendbird sdk. I downloaded the sample ios project in their website https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-iOS.git
But its showing errors when trying to connect.
[image]

Also when I tried to create users through website dashboard, this is what I get :

[image]

Can someone help ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe because it is a sample project, it is not connected to any global storage, either you need to make a local storage for it yourself or create a free account in SendBird website -> Login-> Dashboard -> and then add user manually there.
Link:
 **https://dashboard.sendbird.com/auth/signin**

Comment: I already mentioned about trying to create user but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

when you create your ABC account you're creating an Token for that account too, it means, no-one would be able to login until the token has entered, there're two choices

Add `accessToken=@""` on the signin process in your code, or uncheck the Issue Token

Hope that helps